# Configure IIS using integrated authentication to not allow ie users to use the automatic login option

Tags: iis-7, windows-authentication

Is there a way to always force users to have to enter in their usernames and passwords to a asp.net site that is using integrated windows authenticaton even if they have the option in internet explorer set to automatic logon?  I know a domain policy can set the option for them in ie but due to other circumstances at the client this is not an option, I wont go into details.  I just need it to always prompt for credentials regardless of if that option is selected in ie or not.

Answer (score 1):

Add this section in your config file:

```
<system.web>

  <authentication mode="Windows"/>

 </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, sorry. The only way to force user to enter login/password is to use forms-based authentication.